# Sharpness filter overlay for entire desktop?

Tags: display

You know how there is a sharpness setting for some monitors? My monitor, and old Acer H203 LCD, lacks this feature. I tried power strip software as well as soft MCCS software to no avail.

Is there any way to replicate/emulate this sharpening effect for the entire screen? It could be for Windows or Ubuntu. Even if it's for Mac, I would still be interested to look into the details.

It'd basically be like applying the Photoshop sharpen or unsharp mask setting, but in real time as an overlay to your entire desktop for any application.

Comment: i am looking for software, not a physical product. In my original question when I said "overlay the entire desktop"I did not mean a actual physical screen, but I'm referring to some sort of software filter to do the sharpening effect.

Comment: Any free recommendations for open source or ways to modify windows/ubuntu or addons would be appreciated as well

Comment: ClearType does not achieve the results I am after. Plus, I hope this sharpening effect will enhance anything on my screen, not just text. It is the same sharpness the fact that you can achieve by adjusting the sharpness setting on most televisions and on some monitors.

Comment: Are hardware solutions out of the question?  Why not buy a new(er) monitor?

Comment: Of course it would be best to avoid Having to buy a new monitor, and it is always fun to tinker with software solutions.  =) In addition, from the monitors I've tried that have this sharpness adjustment settings, the results are not all created equal and not always satisfactory. What I really want is the effect of the sharpness adjustment you see in photo editing software like Photoshop, but it can be applied constantly in real time over the entire desktop for any application during use.

Comment: As a workaround, you can consider enlarging your system font size, and/or rendering the display output at a higher resolution, and allowing the monitor or GPU to downscale the picture.  Also check around in your graphics card options, increasing the contrast of the picture and adjusting the brightness/gamma accordingly should give a more sharper appearance of any edges which are displayed.

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions. Trust me I've tinkered plenty with color brightness and contrast in my Nvidia control panel. Too bad  it does not have this sharpness setting. 

 If anyone is familiar with the software called "flux", imagine if flux had a sharpness setting

Comment: @user151426 also, are you connected via a VGA or DVI cable?

Comment: DVI. I use hdmi sometimes too.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to emulate a hardware sharpness control setting in software. You might theoretically be able to hook DWM in Vista or newer so that it'd have the effect of applying a sharpness filter to the entire framebuffer before displaying it, but that would require writing your own code to do so and would incur constant CPU load, and even then it wouldn't overcome whatever failing of your display hardware moves you to ask the question in the first place; your only option there is to replace the display.

Comment: I probably should not have mentioned the failing of my current display because I think many are interpreting me as simply not wanting to buy a new monitor. Regardless of my display, my main interest is in being able to apply a sharpening effect across my entire desktop through some software modification. As you said, this would be something that is theoretically achieved by modifying the DWM in Windows.

Comment: There is a software called sweet FX which can apply a sharpness setting (luma sharpening) through the directX filter in Windows 3-D games, but of course I wish that type of feature could extend to outside of gaming to my entire desktop over any application.